# Unable to Extrude a Plane

Tags: modeling, objects, extrude

Whenever I add an Object or import an SVG object, I am able to extrude it either by <kbd>E</kbd> or by the extrude tool in object data, but I can't do that for a plane ( and just saw for a cube as well ). I get no options for it in the Object Data section nor does Pressing <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude it.
What have I done wrong or not installed?

Comment: Do you have it selected while in edit mode? (Tab toggles edit mode, A toggles selecting everything)

Comment: Can you show us pictures of the problem?

Comment: LOL @gandalf3 i tried it in Edit mode and now it extruded sucessfully, Thanks for your response Knuckles209cp!

Answer (score 2):

In order to edit an object, you must be in [*Edit mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes).

You can set the mode in *3D view > Header*, or by pressing <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: activate Staples button; "that was easy."

Answer (score 0):

When you import a SVG file it will be imported as a curve.

For **Curve Objects** extrusion is set in the Geometry Modification Extrude section. For this operation it doesn't matter if you are in [Edit or Object Mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html?highlight=edit%20mode) (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

[image]

For **Mesh Objects** (not curves, like a plane or a cube), you can only [extrude](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html?highlight=extrude) the geometry in **[Edit Mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html?highlight=edit%20mode)**

[image]