# Imported .svg will not extrude

Tags: faces, extrude, svg

[image: image for extrude] 
I have created an image in Animate (Flash) using fill and stroke and exported as an .svg and also exported from Illustrator. I cannot extrude these as I can with images created in Blender. Please help a noob, thank you :)

Comment: See [my answer here](/questions/71640/modeling-with-curves-coming-from-c4d), specifically the part about the scale problems

Comment: Imported SVGs become a curve not a mesh. You can extrude the curve directly or convert it to a mesh to edit normally. Please read the related lins : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19764/unable-to-extrude-a-plane/46961#46961 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64357/please-explain-how-to-extrude-a-2d-curve-from-svg

Answer (score 1):

**Use the Extrude option for curves.** This let's you keep the SVG as adjustable vector art until you need to convert it to a mesh.

1. **Import your SVG to Blender.** Imported vector art normally comes in as a Blender curve. Depending on the complexity of your SVG, you may need to select all curves with the file and use cntl-J to combine them into a complex curve. Scale it to suit.
2. **Select the SVG, and go to the Curve panel.** The Curve panel offers a range of different options you can use to adjust the resolution, fill type or... lots of things.
3. **Adjust Geometry > Extrude**. This will extrude your SVG at 90-degrees to the plane of the SVG.
4. **(Optional) Shape > Fill > Both**. This might already be on Fill, but this will 'cap' closed curves in the SVG, creating solid pillars of your curve.
5. **(Totally optional) Shape > Resolution > Preview U > [some number]**. Curves have infinite resolution, but eventually you will probably need to convert the curve to a mesh. The 'U' number is the number of segments each line segment will be divided. Use this carefully if you have a combination of very long and very short segments. You may wish to subdivide long segments (or combine short ones) before you apply the 'U' value.
6. **Have fun**. Tip: You can adjust the extrude shape using another curve, providing an interesting way to shape your extrusion.

Demo video: [Extruding SVGs](https://vimeo.com/262133416)

Answer (score 0):

Well first you have to go into object mode and click alt and c on your keyboard which will bring up the following menu:
[image: Convert to Menu]

Click on the last option which is "Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text".

Then go into edit mode and you should be able to extrude like so:
[image: Final Product]